# how to reduce running time in for loop in two list iteration?

Tags: list, numpy, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

In my dataframe there are more than 50k rows, my code is getting more than 30 minutes to run,

dataframe type

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fname':['richard','patricia','william','michael'],
'lname':['dietzen','economides','macdonald','boothby'],
'contact':['+187086706','not available','+124471426','+181773663'],
'bus_contact':['not available','+124789540','+156984476','not available'],
'email':['not available','patricia.econo@gmail.com','dpjpropmanagement@gmail.com','othby@osmifw.com'],
'bus_mail':['rdieen@hotmail.com','wmacdon@mcrtrust.com','not available','michel.booby@yahoo.com'],
'website':['www.chicainexts.com','www.dpjrymanagement.com','www.millplaces.com','www.ofw.co']})
```

The following list is index of the data frame in tuple format

```
multi_idx_val=[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

the expected output is a list that contain the len of intersection of index tuples value, following code is my one but it's taking too much time to run

```
elements_in_all_list = []
for tup in multi_idx_val:

   idx_list_1 = []
   idx_list_2 = []
   list_df1=df[df.index==tup[0]].values.tolist()
   for idx_1,item_1 in enumerate(sum(list_df1,[])):
      if item_1 != 'not available':
          idx_list_1.append(idx_1)

   list_df2=df[df.index==tup[1]].values.tolist()
   for idx_1,item_1 in enumerate(sum(list_df2,[])):
      if item_1 != 'not available':
          idx_list_2.append(idx_1)
   elements_in_all = list(set(idx_list_1).intersection(idx_list_2))
   elements_in_all_list.append(elements_in_all)

count_element = []
for element in elements_in_all_list:
   count_element.append(len(element))
print(count_element)
```

can anyone help using numpy vectorize or other solution for reduce the running time of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
bool_df = df.eq("not available")
out = [(~(bool_df.iloc[a] | bool_df.iloc[b])).sum() for a, b in multi_idx_val]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```